# Equivalent to $\int \cos{\left(2x\right)} \ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

For some reason, I am lost on one part of this integration problem:

> $\begin{align}\int \cos{\left(2x\right)} \ dx\end{align}$
>
> ---
>
> $u = 2x$
>
> $du = 2 \ dx$
>
> $\frac{1}{2} du = dx$
>
> ---
>
> $\begin{align}\frac{1}{2} \int \cos{\left(u\right)} \ du\end{align}$
>
> $\begin{align}\frac{\sin{u}}{2} + C\end{align}$
>
> $\begin{align}\frac{\sin{\left(2x\right)}}{2} + C\end{align}$

The only issue is that I have been told that this should really equal $\sin{x}\cos{x} + C$.
I know that $\sin{\left(2x\right)} = 2\sin{x}\cos{x} + C$, so:

> $\begin{align}\frac{\sin{\left(2x\right)}}{2} = \frac{2\sin{x}\cos{x}}{2} + C = \sin{x}\cos{x} + C\end{align}$

On a question I had asked previously, I was told that $\begin{align} \int \cos{\left(2x\right)} \ dx \neq \frac{\sin{\left(2x\right)}}{2} + C\end{align}$, but rather $\sin{x}\cos{x} + C$.

Please excuse the silly question, but these two expressions are the same, right?

Comment: They *are* equal. Why didn't you link to the old question?

Comment: The two answers are the same.

Comment: @anon You'd have to dig around to find what I'm references.

Comment: All the more reason to provide a link, I would say. -1 for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what question you're referring to, so I can't address the misunderstanding, but

$$\int \cos(2x)dx=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}+C=\sin(x)\cos(x)+C$$

is correct.

Comment: That is because $sin(2x) = 2 sin(x) cos(x)$, which is what he needs to know explicitly